# Cookie not persisting after redirecting in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I'm currently implementing authentication within my application.

Instead of handling authentication myself, I'm using Discord. This issue is not caused by the use of Discord's API specifically.

The logic:

1. User proceeds to http://localhost:3000/auth
2. User clicks on the 'Login with Discord' button, which redirects to Discord's login interface
3. Upon entering correct credentials, Discord redirects the user back to the application with an `access_token`
4. If the `access_token` is present, `express-session` initiates the session and adds `discord_access_token` to the session
5. The user is redirected to the dashboard

The problem:

Everything up to step 5 above works as intended.

Once redirected to `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` by `res.redirect('/dashboard')` in `discordAuthController.js` the cookie is no longer visible in developer tools and therefore the client cannot access the session data. **But** if I go to the `/dashboard` route manually it appears!

Both redirect and manual requests go to the address `http://localhost:3000/dashboard`.

I've tested different routes when redirecting, whenever I use `res.redirect('/ROUTE')` the cookie is not present in client storage unless I refresh or go to the route manually.

http://localhost:3000/auth/discord route file (routes/auth/discord.js)

```
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session'

import * as discordAuthController from '../../app/controllers/auth/discordAuthController.js'

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    await discordAuthController.index(req, res)
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    })
})

export default router
```

/controllers/auth/discordAuthController.js

```
import { exchangeToken } from '../../models/auth/discord.js'

async function index(req, res) {
  await exchangeToken(req.query.code)
  .then(response => {
    req.session.initialised = true
    req.session.discord_user_id = response.access_token

    res.redirect('/dashboard')
  })  
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    res.sendStatus(500)
  })
};

export { index }
```

/models/auth/discord.js

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv' 
dotenv.config()

const api_endpoint = process.env.DISCORD_API_ENDPOINT
const client_id = process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID
const client_secret = process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET
const redirect_uri = process.env.DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI
const guild_id = process.env.DISCORD_GUILD_ID

async function makeExchange(auth_code) {
    return await fetch(api_endpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({
          client_id,
          client_secret,
          grant_type: 'authorization_code',
          code: auth_code,
          redirect_uri
        })
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
}

export async function exchangeToken (auth_code) {
    return await makeExchange(auth_code)
}
```

Comment: What is the step 8 you are describing? In your logic you write till step 5

Comment: I simplified the step numbers but didn't update the reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the application redirect coming from a site with a different domain and the current cookie type set to `strict`, the cookie was behaving normally.

> Lax allows the cookie to be sent on some cross-site requests, whereas Strict never allows the cookie to be sent on a cross-site request ([Simant, 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990864/what-is-the-difference-between-samesite-lax-and-samesite-strict))

After setting the `sameSite` value of the cookie to `lax`, the cookie was loaded by the browser as data was read.